# call an object's member function in std::algorithms (note: this is a different object, not in containers)

Tags: function, member

My code:

```
#include <algorithm>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>  
using namespace std;  

class myClass {  
    public:  
        myClass() {  
            init();  
    }  
    void init() {  
        _myVector.push_back("Hello");  
        _myVector.push_back("World");  
        _myVector.push_back("Bye!");  
        for_each (_myVector.begin(), _myVector.end(), &myClass::print);  
    }  
    void print(string &myStr) {  
        cout << myStr << "." << endl;  
    }  
    private:  
        vector<string> _myVector;  
};  

int main() {  
    myClass myObj;  
    return 0;  
}
```

If _myVector contained myClass objects or pointers, I could use std::mem_fun_ref or std::mem_fun. Is there any way to do the above? And yes, I do not want myClass::print to be static.

Answer (score 0):

```
for_each (_myVector.begin(), _myVector.end(), &myClass::print);
```

to be replaced with

```
for_each (_myVector.begin(), _myVector.end(), bind1st(mem_fun(&myClass::print), this));
```

Comment: But to use the above method, myClass::print has to take string by value. Any way pass by reference and still use similar approach?

Comment: How funny and complicated is that syntax for just a simple thing !